# How to know the GUID of a Database?

Tags: database, sync, guid, service, user

I follow this step by step http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681014.aspx for reset the User Profile Synchronization Service but I need the GUID of the synchronization database. I searched a lot but I didn't find anything. I need also to find the GUID of the/a service.

Thank you

PS: I first asked this question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746330/sharepointhow-to-know-the-guid-of-a-database/8747817#comment10910243_8747817

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both [Get-SPDatabase](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607889.aspx) or [Get-SPContentDatabase](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607828.aspx) powershell cmdlets retrun database GUID (among other attributes), if called without parameters, try to use it.